# Converting a string to DateTime in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime

Now I know this question has been asked several times, and I've gone through dozens of answers, but nothing seems to work for me.. I'm trying to convert a string to datetime in SQL, but get the following error:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
```

This is the query I'm trying to run:

```
SELECT MessageText, 
       CONVERT(datetime,SUBSTRING(MessageText, CHARINDEX('(', MessageText)+1,                   
       CHARINDEX(')', MessageText) - 
       CHARINDEX('(', MessageText)-1)) AS TourTimeStamp, 
       TIMESTAMP
FROM tblMessageLog
WHERE MessageText LIKE 'Tour run timestamp%for tour%has been%'
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
```

So, in `MessageText`, there is the timestamp that I'm looking for (the `TimeStamp` column is actually just the timestamp of the messagelog entry...) and I can successfully get this by using substring.

The format of this substring (`TourTimeStamp`) is: `dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss` e.g. `25/02/2012 20:55:13`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could You include the result of this `SUBSTRING`?

Comment: Grzegorz W - I've edited the question to be more clear; the format of the date I mentioned is the substring I'm getting. So I can successfully get the date from the MessageText field, but it's currently in String format!

Comment: MarcinJuraszek - This is looking at an OSIsoft PI Manual Logger message log database, which logs succesful tours that are recorded using manual loggers.

Comment: @Kyle: I believe Marcin was asking which RDBMS are you using - Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer, PostgreSQL, etc? (They each have different ways of converting between strings and dates.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is MS SQL Server.

Your have to specify the format:
Try this:

```
Select 
  MessageText, 
  CONVERT(
    datetime,
    SUBSTRING(
      MessageText, 
      CHARINDEX('(', MessageText) + 1, 
      CHARINDEX(')', MessageText) - CHARINDEX('(', MessageText) - 1),
    103) 
  AS TourTimeStamp, 
  Timestamp 
FROM 
  tblMessageLog 
WHERE 
  MessageText LIKE 'Tour run timestamp%for tour%has been%' 
ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC
```

Also [look here for list of supported formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms187928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi, this seems to work! I just assumed as DateTime style 103 is defined as dd/mm/yyyy, it would cut the time off (i.e. no hh:mm:ss), and when I tried it it didn't work at first, but that must have been due to another error somewhere... Thanks a lot!